# Need ODBC connection to postgresql to include materialized views

Tags: ms-access, postgresql-9.4, odbc, materialized-view

I have an Access front end user interface that links to tables in a postgreSQL database using the most recent ODBC driver. I can link to the postgreSQL tables and views but can't get to the materialized views.

[This thread](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAB7nPqR0apHpiPAi4J2e3oR2jZ8MREyJAzxdWMjrr4h5PsRp4w@mail.gmail.com#CAB7nPqR0apHpiPAi4J2e3oR2jZ8MREyJAzxdWMjrr4h5PsRp4w@mail.gmail.com) describes a patch to the driver to include materialized views. Does anyone know if this patch is included in the most recent driver? If not, how would I apply it? If it is included, which options need to be selected so that materialized views are accessible from MS Access?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that Postgres views are included in the linked tables within Access. Click on any linked table within Access and within the list should be your views.  I always find it useful within Postgres to preface a view name with 'VIEW_' so that they are all readily visible and accessible within Access.